# Python: How to generate all combinations of lists of tuples without repeating contents of the tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, combinations, python-itertools

I'm working with a bit of a riddle:

Given a dictionary with tuples for keys: `dictionary = {(p,q):n}`, I need to generate a list of new dictionaries of every combination such that neither p nor q repeat within the new dictionary. And during the generation of this list of dictionaries, or after, pick one of the dictionaries as the desired one based on a calculation using the dictionary values.

example of what I mean (but much smaller):

`dictionary = {(1,1): 1.0, (1,2): 2.0, (1,3): 2.5, (1,4): 5.0, (2,1): 3.5, (2,2): 6.0, (2,3): 4.0, (2,4): 1.0}`

becomes

`listofdictionaries = [{(1,1): 1.0, (2,2): 6.0}, {(1,1): 1.0, (2,3): 4.0}, (1,1): 1.0, (2,4): 1.0}, {(1,2): 2.0, (2,1): 3.5}, {(1,2): 2.0,  (2,3): 4.0},` etc.

a dictionary like: `{(1,1): 1.0, (2,1): 3.5}` is not allowable because q repeats.

Now my sob story: I'm brand new to coding... but I've been trying to write this script to analyze some of my data. But I also think it's an interesting algorithm riddle. I wrote something that works with very small dictionaries but when I input a large one, it takes way too long to run (copied below). In my script attempt, I actually generated a list of combinations of tuples instead that I use to refer to my master dictionary later on in the script. I'll copy it below:

*The dictionary tuple keys were generated using two lists: "ExpList1" and "ExpList2"*

```
#first, I generate all the tuple combinations from my ExpDict dictionary
combos =(itertools.combinations(ExpDict,min(len(ExpList1),len(ExpList2))))

#then I generate a list of only the combinations that don't repeat p or q
uniquecombolist = []
for foo in combos:
    counter = 0
    listofp = []
    listofq = []
    for bar in foo:
        if bar[0] in listofp or bar[1] in listofq:
            counter=+1
            break
        else:
            listofp.append(bar[0])
            listofq.append(bar[1])
    if counter == 0:
        uniquecombolist.append(foo)
```

After generating this list, I apply a function to all of the dictionary combinations (iterating through the tuple lists and calling their respective values from the master dictionary) and pick the combination with the smallest resulting value from that function.

I also tried to apply the function while iterating through the combinations picking the unique p,q ones and then checking whether the resulting value is smaller than the previous and keeping it if it is (this is instead of generating that list "uniquecombolist", I end up generating just the final tuple list) - still takes too long.

I think the solution lies in embedding the p,q-no-repeat and the final selecting function DURING the generation of combinations. I'm just having trouble wrapping my head around how to actually do this.

Thanks for reading!
Sara

EDIT:

To clarify, I wrote an alternative to my code that incorporates the final function (basically root mean squares) to the sets of pairs.

```
`combos =(itertools.combinations(ExpDict,min(len(ExpList1),len(ExpList2))))


prevRMSD = float('inf')
for foo in combos:
    counter = 0
    distanceSUM = 0
    listofp = []
    listofq = []
    for bar in foo:
        if bar[0] in listofp or bar[1] in listofq:
            counter=+1
            break
        else:
            listofp.append(bar[0])
           listofq.append(bar[1])
        distanceSUM = distanceSUM + RMSDdict[bar]
    RMSD = math.sqrt (distanceSUM**2/len(foo))
    if counter == 0 and RMSD< prevRMSD:
        chosencombo = foo
        prevRMSD = RMSD`
```

So if I could incorporate the RMS calculation during the set generation and only keep the smallest one, I think that will solve my combinatorial problem.

Comment: Do you want to generate all possible sets of pairs satisfying your criteria? Or the possible size `n` sets of pairs where `n` is the length of the smaller generating list?

Comment: @JaredGoguen each pair is a single entry in the set. The set has n number of pairs in it because p and q cannot repeat so it must be limited to the size of the smaller generating list. I want to generate every possible set, given two lists of tuple pairs (or two dictionaries with tuple keys).

Comment: I tried looking at the code for itertools.combinations but I honestly just can't make enough sense of it to work in my own conditions for combinations and even the final function I need to apply. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24907913/explain-combination-function-of-python-module-itertools but still don't really understand how it works unfortunately. Like I said in my post,  I'm very new to this (I've written one other script and have never taken any courses in computer science) so maybe I'm biting off more than I can chew.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assume that you are trying to generate sets with |S| elements, where S is the smaller pool of tuple coordinates. The larger pool will be denoted L.

Since the set will contain |S| pairs with no repeated elements, each element from S must occur exactly once. From here, match up the *permutations* of L where |S| elements are chosen with the ordered elements of S. This will generate all requested sets **exhaustively and without repetition**.

Note that P(|L|, |S|) is equal to |L|!/(|L|-|S|)!

Depending on the sizes of the tuple coordinate pools, there may be too many permutations to enumerate.

Some code to replicate this enumeration might look like:

```
from itertools import permutations 

S, L = range(2), range(4) # or ExpList1, ExpList2
for p in permutations(L, len(S)):
    print(zip(S, p))
```

In total, your final code might look something like:

```
S, L = ExpList1, ExpList2
pairset_maker = lambda p: zip(S, p)

if len(S) > len(L):
    S, L = L, S
    pairset_maker = lambda p: zip(p, S)

n = len(S)   
get_perm_value = lambda p: math.sqrt(sum(RMSDdict[t] for t in pairset_maker(p))**2/n)

min_pairset = min(itertools.permutations(L, n), key=get_perm_value)
```

If this doesn't get you to within an order or magnitude or two of your desired runtime, then you might need to consider an algorithm that doesn't produce an optimal solution.

Comment: Yes, I've come to realize this, which is why I would ideally like to apply my function during the generation of combinations...In the end I use a function to find the set of tuples that computes the smallest value, so if I could incorporate that function into the code generating unique sets such that it checks each new combination to see if it's smaller than the previous one and then keeps the smaller of the two, I think that could work? What do you think?

Comment: also I am looking for combinations rather than permutations

Comment: There is a one-to-one mapping between the combinations of the pairs as you describe them and the permutations of L described in the answer above.

Comment: Does the code snippet not produce the sets of pairs that you'd expect?

Comment: Also, the objects generated by `itertools` and generators, which means that they are lazy and do not produce elements until needed (i.e. there is no giant list of permutations floating in memory). So, applying your functions to the tuple and only keeping the greater one wouldn't do anything I don't think.

Comment: Thanks for you help Jared. I was unable to come back and work on this until tonight. I agree with your comment above about it may having too many permutations to enumerate... no matter how I go about it. I need to think of an entirely different way to do what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem, you are interested in all the possible combinations of pairs (p,q) with unique p's and q's respecting a given set of possible values for p's and q's. In my answer I assume those possible values are, respectively, in `list_p` and `list_q` (I think this is what you have in `ExpList1` and `ExpList2` am I right?)

```
min_size = min(len(list_p), len(list_q))

combos_p = itertools.combinations(list_p, min_size)
combos_q = itertools.permutations(list_q, min_size)
prod = itertools.product(combos_p, combos_q)
uniquecombolist = [tuple(zip(i[0], i[1])) for i in prod]
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. By the way welcome to SO, great question!

---

Edit:

If you're concerned that your list may become enormous, you can always use a generator expression and apply whatever function you desire to it, e.g.,

```
min_size = min(len(list_p), len(list_q))

combos_p = itertools.combinations(list_p, min_size)
combos_q = itertools.permutations(list_q, min_size)
prod = itertools.product(combos_p, combos_q)
uniquecombo = (tuple(zip(y[0], y[1])) for y in prod) # this is now a generator expression, not a list -- observe the parentheses

def your_function(x):
    # do whatever you want with the values, here I'm just printing and returning
    print(x)
    return x

# now prints the minimum value
print(min(itertools.imap(your_function, uniquecombo)))
```

When you use generators instead of lists, the values are computed as they are needed. Here since we're interested in the minimum value, each value is computed and is discarded right away unless it is the minimum.

Comment: I think I will still run into the problem of the list being too large to determine which set of tuple pairs is the one yielding the smallest final value (after inputting each set into the function). I'll edit the above post to include my function. I left it out to keep this post more general but I think it will help readers understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ir this is indeed what you want, I’ll try to explain a bit better what I did

Comment: It does elegantly solve the first round of set selection though! Thanks :) Let me know what you think of my edit above

Comment: Generality is great and this is what you should seek when posting on Stack Overflow. I'll check your edit.

Comment: So it seems that you are concerned with generating a list way too big before you apply your function. If this is the case, you don't need to generate the list first, use a generator expression instead. I'll show you how

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delayed reply. I've been very busy with other school work.. this script is a little side project/brain teaser. So I tried the above tonight and again it works but also crashes my computer if I try with lists longer than 5 or 6 entries. I think I need to go about this in a completely different way that doesn't necessitate finding and computing for every combination in my list. With this method, the run time is always going to increase by a factorial with input size (as pointed out by Jared above). Thank you very much for your help, this was fun regardless!